# One to Many projections using QueryDSL with Spring

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to use QueryDSL in Spring Boot and it was working just fine until I bumped into a problem that I'm not finding an answer. Suppose that I have the following structure:

```
+-------+          +----------+          +-------+
| foo   |          | foo_bar  |          | bar   |
+-------+          +----------+          +-------+
| id    | -------->| foo_id   |       +- | id    |
| name  |          | bar_id   |<------|  | name  |
+-------+          | position |          +-------+
                   +----------+
```

I'm trying to use `Projections` from QueryDSL to manage my service response, so I have the classes defined like:

Foo.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    // Relations

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    private List<FooBar> fooBars;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

FooBar.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_bar")
public class AlbumView{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int position;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
    private Bar bar;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Bar.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    // Relations

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bar")
    private List<FooBar> fooBars;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Now in my controller I'm trying to do the following code to return `Foo` with his `FooBars` where `Bar` id is 1. The query kind of works, because it returns only the `Foo`'s that have `Bar` id equals 1, but it I don't know how to get the `position` attribute that is inside the relation table.

```
JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
QFoo foo = QFoo.foo;
QFooBar fooBar = QFooBar.fooBar;

return query.from(foo)
        .join(foo.fooBars, fooBar).on(fooBar.bar.id.eq((long)1))
        .list(Projections.bean(Foo.class,
                foo.id,
                foo.name,
                Projections.bean(FooBar.class,
                        ???
                        // foo.fooBars.position can't be used because fooBars is an array
                        // foo.fooBars.get(0).position can't be used because i throws NullPointerException
                ).as("fooBars")
            )
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a random guess: Have to tried to use `foo.fooBars.any().position`?